# TypeError: unbound method set_rank() must be called with Link instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, django

when i run 
    (nohup python -u rerank.py&)

I have the following :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "rerank.py", line 24, in <module>
   rank_all()
   File "rerank.py", line 11, in rank_all
   Link.set_rank()
 TypeError: unbound method set_rank() must be called with Link instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

my file rerank.py looks like this and I don't find any gem

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import os
   import django

   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "news_factory.settings")
   django.setup()
   from news.models import Link

   def rank_all():
   for link in Link.with_votes.all():
    Link.set_rank()

    import time


    def show_all():
     print "\n".join("%10s %0.2f" % (l.title, l.rank_score,) for l in 
     Link.with_votes.all())

    print "----\n\n\n"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
     while 1:
      print "---"
      rank_all()
      show_all()
      time.sleep(5)
```

I really thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Link.set_rank()` to `link.set_rank()` or to `Link.set_rank(link)`

The current version looks up *set_rank* on the class but doesn't pass in the `link` instance to operate on.  We call that an "unbound method".

The suggested revisions either make a "bound method" by doing the lookup on the *link* instance or just passes *link* directly into the the unbound method.  Both ways work, though the first is shorter, faster, and usually preferred.